# toxin determination and treatment of wild water

Tags: bacterial-toxins, treatment

I am writing an article on the treatment of wild water from a wilderness survival angle. I have come across the term "toxin" and am finding it hard to produce a determination and treatment strategy.

It is first difficult to advise if a water source contains toxins, other than the presence of algal blooms. For example, a lake had blue-green algae. I understand that the associated toxin is produced by the cyanobacteria, but not the bacteria itself.

Pathogen treatment would be boiling or if available, chemicals such as iodine, chlorine or chlorine dioxide. Chemically contaminated water would require distilling.

I don't know if I can treat water containing toxins at all without distilling it or if there are different strategies for different toxins.